# get an element by id xml document

Tags: c#, xml

Can someone help me get the an elemnt by id?

For example if I have some thing like:

```
<abc>
    <x>tghgh</x>
    <y>fgghj</y>
    <z>dghj</z>
</abc>
```

If I say `getelement(3)` it should return me `element.name` as `Z` and `element.value` as `dghj`.

Is there already a function which I am missing or is there a way I can code this?

Comment: Why won't you check out [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?

Comment: `3` is not the id of anything here. At best it's an index, but your sample is open for multiple interpretations. Should the index be flattened or are we counting inside `<abc>` ?

Comment: sorry.. dint see your replies :(.. yeah i need the index.. counting inside abc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 using System.Xml.Linq;


 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);  
 var target = doc.Element("abc").Elements().ElementAt(2);
```

Note the counting starts at 0, so it's ElementAt(2).

Finding the element with tag `z` is easier and faster:

```
 var target = doc.Element("abc").Element("z");
```

In both cases you have `target.Name` and `target.Value`